# Openstreetmaps API

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to get few results from Openstreetmaps data. Such as I will submit a city/postal code and in return I want to get all street name within the city/postal code. This can easily done by full OSM setup and PostGIS but for this few need I do not want to setup huge database. Is there any way to retrieve the data? There is an old API called openstreetmap API v.0.6. But I am not sure whether it can fulfill my purpose or not.

Comment: Main OSM API should be used only for editing purpose, contributing to database. Not for queries. Use Overpass-api for queries.

Answer (score 1):

**Mapquest** uses OpenstreetMap data in there Open Data products.

Services that Mapquest provide are available for **free** and these services can be consumed directly:

- Open Directions API Web Service
- Open Guidance API Web Service
- Open Geocoding API Web Service
- Open Static Map Web Service
- Open Elevation API Web Service
- Nominatim API Web Service
- Xapi API Web Service

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open

Comment: Thank you very much for expertise answer. Can you let me know a little bit by which API I can query a postal code that returns all the street names within the postcode?

Comment: example: http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=<api-key>&outFormat=xml&postalCode=ls61bq&country=UK

Answer (score 0):

Look out for the Overpass API. It allows better filtering than the original OSM API, and is much quicker.